# Review late answers to old questions asking for tools or libraries: What should I do?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, answers

What should I do when I have to review a late answer to an old question asking for tools or libraries?

A few days ago, I had an answer to review to an old question. I flagged the answer as spam and my flag was declined. I do not contest it: in addition to a link for a tools, the answer contains a part of the answer to question.

But I have seen later that the question has been closed. So I am not sure about what  should be do now.

I just had an answer to review, answer to this old question:   [Best Static Photo Gallery Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620947/best-static-photo-gallery-generator). The answer is a link-only answer, but it is what is asked. So:

- I skipped the answer (I can't say this is not an answer)
- I flagged the question to be closed (*Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*)

Is it the correct thing to do? Or what should I do instead (with the answer And the question)?

Comment: It is correct to just flag the question to be close (or cast close vote if you got the rep for it).